# Laravel, can't set old value to bootstrap datetimepicker, when validate

Tags: laravel, datetimepicker

I'm using Laravel 8.5 (current version)

Therefore I'm new to laravel, I'm trying to learn with simple examples.

I have some blade view, with code part bellow:

```
             <div class="form-group">
                <input type="hidden" id="hdnLocale" value="ru">
                <input type="hidden" name="hdndefDate" id="hdndefDate" value="2021-01-17">
                @if (old('hdndefDate'))
                <input type="hidden" name="hdndefDate" value="{{ old('hdndefDate') }}">
                @endif
                <label for="picker">Birthday</label>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <button type="button" class="input-group-text" id="toggle">
                            <i class="fa fa-calendar-alt"></i>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <input type="text" id="picker" name="picker" value="{{old('picker')}}" class="form-control" readonly>
                </div>
            </div>
```

As you see I'm using two hidden inputs, with a variable value from the controller, that must be set from javaScript (In a simple I use exact value).

Here is my script:

```
 <script>
        var locale = $('#hdnLocale').val()
        jQuery.datetimepicker.setLocale(locale)
        jQuery.datetimepicker.setDateFormatter('moment')

        var yourDate = $('#hdndefDate').val();
        $('#picker').val(yourDate);
        $('#picker').datetimepicker({
            timepicker: false,
            datepicker: true,
            format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
            defaultDate: yourDate,
            weeks: false,
            hours12: false,
            step: 15,
            yearStart: 2015,
            yearEnd: 2022,
            dayOfWeekStart: 1
        });

        $('#toggle').on('click', function () {
            $('#picker').datetimepicker('toggle');
        })

</script>
```

I have some other inputs also, that I've validating via the controller,
when I change the value of datepicker, post form and validation fails, other fields set with old values, except datepicker.
Where I have messed something? I wanna set the old value to datepicker, when validation fails.
As I discovered later, the old value is set and immediately refreshed with default value '2021-01-17'

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're getting two inputs with name hdndefDate when old values from this input exists.

And in your JS you're getting the value from the input #hdndefDate, that holds the default value.

Change your @if to something like this:

```
                @if (old('hdndefDate'))
                    <input type="hidden" name="hdndefDate" id="hdndefDate" value="{{ old('hdndefDate') }}">
                @else
                    <input type="hidden" name="hdndefDate" id="hdndefDate" value="2021-01-17">
                @endif
```

Or even better:

```
<input type="hidden" name="hdndefDate" id="hdndefDate" value="{{ old('hdndefDate') ??  2021-01-17}}">
```